# Speed Coordinate shows null value in GeoLocation PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

i am creating android  application that gets Lat Lng and check the speed of user i am using PhoneGap GeoLocation Api but i am getting only Longitude and Latitude but in Altitude and Speed it shows null
here is the JavaScript that i get from PhoneGap website

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('time');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
        'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '<br />';

        setTimeout('loop();',100);
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    function loop(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

</script>
```

I am check this in Android Mobile as well as emulator same result both places that is null 
The Html part is

```
<body>
<p id="time">Finding geolocation...</p>
```

Comment: [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#coordinates_interface): "The speed attribute denotes the magnitude of the horizontal component of the hosting device's current velocity and is specified in meters per second. If the implementation cannot provide speed information, the value of this attribute must be null. Otherwise, the value of the speed attribute must be a non-negative real number." - Looks like your device/emulator does not support getting speed informations

Comment: @Andreas -- how can i check that my device supports or not for getting speed information? ANy Idea please

Comment: If `speed` is not `null`...?!

Comment: ok then i am going to be some other device thanks @Andreas

Comment: i test this application "Ulysse Speedometer By binarytoys" and it gives the speed of moving object so i think my device is supporting  @Andreas

Comment: Then maybe it is configurable in your emulator. But that's beyond my knowledge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#coordinates_interface)

it might be device specific, as to whether or not those parameters are supported "If the implementation cannot provide {those variables you're having trouble with} information, the value of this attribute must be null."